# EXCEL separate values from right with delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with a bunch of Addresses. I would like to separate those addresses into states and zip codes. These have comma as a delimiter. But the issue is some addresses have more commas then others so if I use text to column function then it will just split those addresses into many columns and it will be hards to organize states and zips in one column.

I had this function which does this but it's not working anymore.

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>last()-3]"),COLUMN(A1))
```

So I would like to know how can I separate the value from a cell with comma delimiter from the right in a range lets say one comma from right, two commas from the right.

**Sample Addresses:**

> Somwhere elseSan Jose, CA 95131
>
> 11757 West Ken Caryl Avenue, Unit KLittleton, CO 80127-3719
>
> 7800 North Mo Pac Expressway, Suite 325Austin, TX 78759-8959

Hoping for some answers.

Comment: why is that not working?  It should do what you ask.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting #VALUE! error.

Comment: can you post some examples of the strings you are trying to parse.  This will help us replicate the problem and find solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated my question with sample string.

Comment: I changed the `-3` to `-2` and it worked for me, no errors.  What version are you using?

Comment: Also I think your examples are missing the comma between the street and the town.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner I changed the -3 to -2 and it also worked for me :)